# Proving existence of limits in $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Let there exist a complex limit $L$, such that,

$$L = \lim_{z\to N} f(z), \ni N,z \in \mathbb C$$

How does one verify that $L$ exists, as one has to check not only the left hand limit or the right hand limit, but infinite more directions! That is because the complex plane is $2$ dimensional.

So, how does one prove that $L$ exists, like we do with number in $\mathbb R$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are several things wrong with your statement that need to be fixed if we are to understand what you are asking and therefore help you. Number one: You say limit as $x$ goes to $N$, but there is only $z$ in $f(z)$. Is there a connection between $x$ and $z$, or are they supposed to be the same? Number two: What does $\ni N$ mean? Also, a technical nitpick: it's enough to use two dollar signs for what you've written, and it also makes the spacing look better. In other words, you don't have to encase every single symbol in their own pair of dollar signs.

Comment: Sorry for the $x$, it was a mistake. $\ni$ refers to "such that".

Comment: Also thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of convergence in $\mathbb{C}$ is the same as in $\mathbb{R}$:

$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, s.t. \forall n > N$$

$$|x_n-L|<\epsilon$$

Note that the modulus of a complex number is the distance to the origin, i.e. is a real number

Comment: So is the epsilon delta definition of a limit a generalization to $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Basically, this definition says that no matter how small circle we create around $L$, from some point on, all of the elements of the sequence will be in this circle(this follows from the $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$ bit) Hence, you are not really interested in the direction of convergence, you know that you can get arbitrarily close to the limit for all elements from some point on

Comment: Oh i see, thanks!